# Is it possible to figure out the code used to build a Wordpress page from a permalink (slug)?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Given a Wordpress permalink (or slug), is there a way to track backwards to figure out the code that generates the displayed page?  For example, using this URL "my.domain.com/product-category/lamps/" or "my.domain.com/product-category/tables/" can you track the code used to make up the page that is displayed in the browser?

Basically, here is my problem.  I've been hired to complete/fix a Wordpress site that was heavily, heavily modified by the original programmer (who quit and is not available to help). The site uses the Stylo Theme with WooCommerce.  The code to build the product catalog pages has been modified and I'm having a hard time finding all the PHP functions that do these modifications.  There are no pages in the control panel that have a permalink that corresponds to the URL (shown above); so I don't even know what template he has used to start these pages.  He did not write a widget or plugin to make these changes, but changed the original code.  His modifications broke (or deliberately disabled) some of the search functionality (min and max price range) built into the theme.

So, back to my question - given the final permalink displayed in the browser's address bar, can I backtrack the code 'path' used to build the page?

Comment: If the platform is, as you say, heavily modified, the first thing I'd do is install Xdebug, and step through the code. Have a pen and paper handy, write down oddities and sketch up a basic flow to get an idea of how the site works. I'd also use Xprof to locate the bottlenecks, and use a sniffer to see what code is used where, and how. Any decent sniffer will also be able to give you an overview of in-code documentation (comments). Install a decent API, too, and don't forget to pray that there are some tests written. All in all, this is not a SO question, and will be closed, I think

Comment: usually the slug corresponds to an path or id or parameters of the url, and usually there must be a lookuptable (slug->url) somewhere

Comment: Have you tried turning Permalinks off, so you could see the full route? (Settings -> Permalinks)

Comment: @TiborB. - thanks, that was one of the first things I tried.  But, everything was set to default.  He somehow bypassed the default settings to force the permalinks.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem - I might end up still using your suggestion to figure out a lot of the other 'stuff' this programmer has done.  But for now, the code provided by Pelmered (below) has given me what I needed.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: @seveninstl: I'd recommend you install Xdebug either way. Even if you're not going to use it right away, learning to set up & use a debugger is an elementary skill. Correction: I recommended to install a decent _API_ in my original comment, that should've read _IDE_, obviously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an easy way to get the path of the template file that is used to render the current request. Place the code in functions.php in your theme or in a plugin and this will print the path on top of your site.

```
add_filter ( 'template_include', 'debug_template_dump' );
function debug_template_dump( $template_path ) { 
    echo $template_path;
    return $template_path;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my experience in similar circumstances, the easiest way to proceed is this:
1. Log in to the site. Make sure you have the wordpress admin bar enabled.
2. View the page in question from the front end.
3. Select 'edit post' or 'edit page' or whatever is offered

The link you supplied is likely to be for a woocommerce product category. Customization was probably performed either using templates (look for a woocommerce folder in your theme) or by utilizing hooks to add custom functions (look in functions.php).

Comment: Thanks, I did do this.  But it was directing me to the category listing for the product and not the page(s) (code) that were actually being used to create the final visible page.  It's almost as if the original programmer was creating a maze, daring someone to follow.